# Error loading shared library libSDL-1.2

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu, shared-library

I've tired to compile ToME 3 game but I can't run it, I've got:

```
tome3: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared
object file: No such file or directory
```

I have installed libstd1.2 both devel and runtime packages. I have that library

```
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL_image-1.2.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL_image-1.2.so.0.8.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDLmain.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL.so
```

I've tried to put `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` into PATH and also copy libSDL-1.2.so.0 to the directory where I have the game, but it not work.

Someone ask the same [question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201202/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libsdl-1-2-so-0) the solution was to reinstall the lib but it don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `ldd` on the game's binary (`t-engine`) to see what exactly it's looking for and whether it resolves.

See the paths that are searched and what is found by using `strace -e file t-engine`. If you see some paths being searched for libSDL but not the path where your libSDL is (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`), then see if you can figure out why.

My guess is that t-engine is compiled for i386 (32-bit) and your SDL libraries are compiled for x86_64 (64-bit).

Comment: It show `libSDL-1.2.so.0 => not found; libSDL_net-1.2.so.0 => not found; libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0 => not found` but all other point to files in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`

Comment: How to compile it using 64bit?

Comment: That's specific to the game you compiled -- usually a `./configure` script will auto-detect which platform (or will use your compiler's default). Check the game documentation.

Comment: If the game is 32-bit only, you can just install the 32-bit versions of the SDL libraries, using something like `apt-get install libsdl1.2:i386`

Comment: that file wasn't there, so I need to install `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev:i386 libglu1-mesa-dev:i386 libglu-dev:i386` bump into this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-lib/+bug/1296474 then also install `libsdl-mixer1.2-dev:i386` and `libsdl-net1.2-dev:i386` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an entry somewhere in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ for your library/library's directory ?

try

`ldconfig -vp |grep SDL-1.2`

if you've installed a new library, then you should simply refresh

```
sudo ldconfig -v
```

Comment: I have `libSDL-1.2.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0` entry. When you install lib using apt-get it run ldconfig automatically.